# How to square matrix elements in R using loops and apply function

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix that I have made in R. I am being asking to square all the numbers in the matrix. First using loops and then using the apply function. I have done the following already.

```
myMatrix = matrix ( c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

So that gives me my matrix. Then I used this to square them

```
 myMatrix * myMatrix ##don't know how to make a loop to do this
```

And finally my attempt to use the apply() function to do the same thing

```
  apply(myMatrix, c(1,2), exp) ##this gave me numbers that didnt look correct
```

Any help in the right direction would be very nice.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `exp` if you are wanting to square each term? Is this what you want for the `apply` ; `apply(m, c(1,2), function(i) i^2)`

Comment: yeah, messed that up, i believe that apply(myMatrix, c(1,2), function(x)x^2) will take care of the apply function, now I just need the loop. Just not sure how to loop something like that in R

Comment: why not simply myMatrix^2 ?

Comment: Because I am forced to use a loop and the apply function

Comment: Wrtiing out the loop shows that this isn't a sensible approach as R vectorises these calculations but anyways:  `out <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(m), ncol=ncol(m)); for(r in 1:nrow(m)) { for(c in 1:ncol(m)){     out[r, c] <- m[r, c]*m[r, c]   }}`

Comment: That's why I thought it was an odd request from the professor, we were told to almost never use loops in R because of the system resources it hogs up.

Comment: This is a really terrible homework problem. It's trying (presumably) to illustrate the use of apply, but it's doing it for something that has a much better solution. I would propose an improvement: (Part a) use the apply function to calculate the mean of each column (you could use `colMeans`, but we'll ignore that for now), (Part b) use `apply()` with a custom function to calculate the max value minus the min value for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some comments mentioned, these are not the best approach to squaring a matrix. But since you asked...

### Using a loop:

```
myMatrix = matrix ( c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3, ncol=3)

# empty matrix for the results
squaredMatrix = matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)

for(i in 1:nrow(myMatrix)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(myMatrix)) {

    squaredMatrix[i,j] = myMatrix[i,j]^2 

  }
}
```

### Edit:

As noted in a comment below, you can also use a single loop:

```
squaredMatrix = matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)
for (i in 1:length(myMatrix)) {
  squaredMatrix[i] <- myMatrix[i]^2
}
```

### Using the `apply` function:

```
squaredMatrix = apply(myMatrix, c(1,2), function(x) x^2)
```

Comment: You can also do `apply(myMatrix, c(1,2), '^',2)`

Comment: Matrices are just vectors with dimensions. No need to double loop  - `for (i in 1:length(myMatrix)) squaredMatrix[i] <- myMatrix[i]^2`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But you don't need to assign `squaredMatrix` as a vector to start with. Matrixes **are already** essentially vectors and can be indexed like one.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is highly inefficient; Instead one should realize that the "^" operator works in an element wise fashion and use:

```
sqrdMtx <- myMatrix^2
```

The "^" operator is not matrix power when its arguments are matrices. For that you need matpow in pkg:expm.